# Trabajar con informacion Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy tratando de tomar la información de un Google Spreadsheet y pegarla en otro Spreadsheet, puedo tomar la información del primer Spreadsheet. Pero no puedo pegarla en el siguiente.
Aparece el siguiente error:

> "Exception: Los parámetros () no coinciden con la firma de método de SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange. (línea 20, archivo "Código")".

```
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11KZM6--z4Mt4gVye-RkfzFfcGCIpAUGPk0vvDA6QGDs/edit?usp=sharing';
  var gente = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var nombre = "nombres";
  var hoja = gente.getSheetByName(nombre);
  var data = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();
  newSheet(data)
}
function newSheet(data)
{
  var nuevo = SpreadsheetApp.create("Nuevo");
  var hojaN = nuevo.getActiveSheet();
  hojaN.getRange().setValue(data);
}
```

Comment: El código no está completo. Pareciera que falta la primer línea de la declaración de la primer función.

Answer (score 1):

El error que indicas en la pregunta se debe a la siguiente línea

```
hojaN.getRange().setValue(data);
```

El método `getRange` debe tener parámetros de las siguientes formas:

```
getRange(row, column)
getRange(row, column, numRows)
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
getRange(a1Notation)
```

Puedes consultar los detalles en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Comment: Claro, pero si hago un Logger.log(data), me muestra la informacion que tome del primer SpreadSheet, el problema lo tengo al pegarlo en el otro Spreadsheet

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el problema lo tengo al pegarlo en el otro Spreadsheet". ¿has intentado usar getRange con parámetros? Si es así, ¿Qué parámetros has usado?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar **[appendrow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))()** para insertar las filas.

```
 function newSheet(data){
   var nuevo = SpreadsheetApp.create("Nuevo");
   var hojaN = nuevo.getActiveSheet().activate();
    
   for (i in data){
        hojaN.appendRow(data[i]);
   }
}
```